# How to do vertical center while height is auto?

Tags: css, html, center, vertical-alignment

i got a small issue with some CSS.

My Container got a static width, but a flexible height. Now i want centering my container vertically but i dont know how.

Could you may help me?

```css
section article {
        position: absolute;
        width: 350px;
        height: auto;
        right: 10%;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 15px;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
```

```html
 <section>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Headline</h1>
                    <h2>Title</h2>
                </header>
                <p>content content content</p>
            </article>
        </section>
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to center? the `article` tag inside of section?

Comment: yes - Jimmy just helped me - thanks to everybody!

Comment: Let's mark that as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the article vertically by first moving it down 50% and then moving it up 50% of it's own height, resulting in it being centered.

```
section article {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    right: 10%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    top: 50%; // move down 50% of container
    transform: translateY(-50%); // move up 50% of it's own height  
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ose0ujy1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know you are able to get hight of the container with css. have a nice day =)

Comment: But transform has lack of browser [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: I assume that these days people don't care about IE8.
[Support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=translate)